# Optmising Cost for Elastic Beanstalk Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services

I have launched a rails app on my AWS account using EB - up until now I was on free tier so wasn't really concerned with optimising the services to reduce cost, however the last month bill came in at ~$60 USD which is too expensive for a small app.

my config is all default except I just changed my EC2 instance to t2.nano from micro.

here is my config screen shot https://i.stack.imgur.com/wODAv.jpg

My app has very little traffic at the moment and will run on minimum specs - so is there any of these services I can disable or remove (perhaps the load balancer?) that will save me cost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is probably too late, but for an application this simple you can disable the Elastic Load Balancer (ELB you should see billed) by selecting Invidivual Instance in your Capacity section in the environment configuration. It won't scale, but it will save you 25 dollars a month in ELB.